# Regex replace for equal sign in whole file

Tags: regular-expression

I'm trying to do a simple replace for all equal signs and subsequent characters until end of line: `%s/\=.+\n/\n/`. However this gives `E866: (NFA regexp) Misplaced =`.

If I try instead to simply replace all equal signs with `%s/(\=)//`, I get pattern not found though I know my text file contains equal signs.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming you are using the default and recommend setting of `'magic'`, you need to use `=` instead of `\=`, `\+` instead of `+`, and `\r` instead of `\n` in the replacement text:

Try this:

```
:%s/=.\+\n/\r
```

But actually, you don't need to match and replace the newline, so this simplifies further:

```
:%s/=.\+
```